# Symfony infrastructure related configuration (env) for multiple mail recipients

Tags: arrays, json, symfony, environment-variables

I migrate a Symfony 3.4 application to symfony 4.3 with .env-File. In my old application a local parameters.yml-file contains a collection of JSON-Values. What is the best practise for dealing with arrays/json in  the new Symfony .env configuration?

For some events the application sends mails. The recipient(s) are infrastructure-related. On dev the mails must be send to the developer on test to one or more tester. In production the mail must be send to two other recipients. Using a database for this configuration is oversized (only a little!).

```
mortages_recipients:
        - { mail: 'recipient_1@example.com', name: 'Name 1' }
        - { mail: 'recipient_2@example.com', name: 'Name 2' }
```

In the documentation I found nothing about this.
What is best practise to define these recipients infrastructure related?

Comment: Nothing inherently wrong in using parameters for this sort of data.  With respect to development, it is easy to have all emails sent to a [particular address](https://symfony.com/doc/4.2/email/dev_environment.html#sending-to-a-specified-address-es).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use the Built-In [Environment Variable Processors](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/env_var_processors.html#built-in-environment-variable-processors).

Set the recipient-list as json-array in the `.env` like:

```
RECIPIENTS="[{mail:'recipient_1@example.com',name:'Name 1'},{mail:'recipient_2@example.com',name:'Name 2'}]"
```

Set the `mortages_recipients` parameter in `services.yaml` to use the JSON env var processor.

```
parameters:
    mortages_recipients: '%env(json:RECIPIENTS)%'
```